# Как получить метаданные о видео файле и сформировать картинку-превью?

Tags: javascript

Задача для выполнения на клиенте. Поиск в гугле пока приводит в никуда, может кто сталкивался или случайно натыкался на что-то подобное? Конкретно, необходимо определить длительность воспроизведения файла и вытащить какую-то картинку из него на превью.

UPD. Браузеры все современные. ОС предпочтительно семейства Windows. Файл попадает путём выбора пользователем из поля ввода типа file. Если есть другие варианты - буду рад советам.

Comment: Какая среда, браузер ?? если браузер то за браузер и как видео попадает в браузер, загружает пользователь или с сайта грузится ? Пока нет доп информации сложно сказать что-то конкретно , но возможно поможет это http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="file" id="file-input" />
<img id="preview-image" style="width: 300px" />

<script>
const input = document.getElementById('file-input');
const preview = document.getElementById('preview-image');

input.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    const video = document.createElement('video');

    video.addEventListener('loadeddata', function(e) {
        const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        // необходимо установить те же размеры, что и у загруженного видео, иначе превью будет обрезано
        canvas.width = this.videoWidth;
        canvas.height = this.videoHeight;

        const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, this.videoWidth, this.videoHeight);

        const dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(); // вот и ссылка с превью
        preview.src = dataURL;

        console.log(this.duration); // а здесь длительность видео в секундах
    });
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
});
</script>
```

В примере извлекается только первый кадр из видео. Если нужен какой-либо другой, посмотрите тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19175174/capture-frames-from-video-with-html5-and-javascript.

На windows к сожалению проверить не могу, на macOS работает в FF, Chrome и Safari последних версий.

Comment: попробовал я этот способ для аудио, и чет не всегда правильно длину отдает